# how can i block website?

Tags: c#

Code:

```
string path = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
string sitetoblock = "\r\n127.0.0.1 http://" + textBox1.Text +
    " 127.0.0.1 http://www." + textBox1.Text;

sw.Write(sitetoblock);
sw.Close();
MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + " blocked");
```

this is a code to block website,....but  it is not working... sometime it works.. how can i block website ?

tell me what is right way to block website.

Comment: Be advised than some antivirus software will red flag this sort of behavior. Many viruses and spyware applications do this kind of thing, say to make microsoft.com point to something else.

Answer (score 6):

First, this is not an effective method to block websites, but if you really want to do it this way, then look up the format of the hosts file.

If you want to block a website by essentially hijacking the DNS lookup, you need to redirect the hostname only.

The hosts file you are generating looks something like this:

127.0.0.1  http://website/file

What you want to see in the file is this:

127.0.0.1 website

Comment: I've been trying to block websites for a couple months now using the hosts file and thanks to this comment it now finally works. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Many Spyware/Adware programs block access to the hosts file. So there is a big chance you may fail doing it this way. Imho it would be better to block the URL in the firewall

Answer (score 0):

The 'hosts' file maps IP addresses to hostnames, so it doesn't need the protocol bits and pieces.

You should be aiming to write "127.0.0.1 hostname" to the file, e.g. to block 'badsite.com' you'd add:

```
127.0.0.1 badsite.com
127.0.0.1 www.badsite.com
```

There are probably better ways to block a site though ;-)

Comment: Maybe a caching issue - close and re-open your browser.  Or open a new command line and try 'ping www.badsite.com' and check what IP address it resolves to.

Comment: if someone type google.com but it is not block.. in browser google opens with google.co.in link

Comment: It's a cache problem for sure. I already played around with the hosts-file today. Sometimes it took some minutes until the changes affected the browser. If u wanna get sure, just restart the computer. It should work then.